# Add another user to MySQL in Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

Here is my MySQL

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc-def-my-mysql
  namespace: abc-sk-test
  labels:
    project: abc
    ca: my
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc-def-my-mysql
        project: abc
        ca: my
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.6
        args: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password", "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "root"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: "my_abc"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: "test_user"
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: "12345"
        volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
           name: abc-def-my-mysql-storage
      volumes:
      - name: abc-def-my-mysql-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: abc-def-my-mysql-pvc
```

I would like to add another user to mysql so real users can connect to it. Instead of using "test_user". how can I add another user, is it like adding any other environment variable to the above config

Answer (score 5):

Mount a "create user script" into container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. it will be executed once, at first pod start.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql
    .....
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: "root"
    .....
    volumeMounts:
      - name: mysql-initdb
        mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  volumes:
  - name: mysql-initdb
    configMap:
      name: initdb

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: initdb
data:
  initdb.sql: |-
    CREATE USER 'first_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '111' ;
    CREATE USER 'second_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '222' ;
```

Test:

```
kubectl exec -it <PODNAME> -- mysql -uroot -p -e 'SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;'

    +-------------+------+
    | user        | host |
    +-------------+------+
    | first_user  | %    |
    | second_user | %    |
    | root        | %    |
    +-------------+------+
```

See [Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) Mysql Docker Hub image:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions `.sh,` `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order.
>
> You can easily populate your `mysql` services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Comment: This is nice, but ConfigMaps are not obscured. Storing this in a repository is probably not a good idea. Might be better to just mount a `.sh` and rely on some environment variable secrets to populate users if set.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on user life-cycle, you can create user either at container startup, either through MySQL's docker startup script, mounted at /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, or you could do it at CLI, after the server has started.

With container startup script, you may have to take care of multiple containers running the same script, e.g. `CREATE user if exists`.

CLI option may be more suitable if the DB server is long lived, and you will get requests for multiple user creation even after server creation.