# Add users to a Kubernetes deployment of MySQL with secrets

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

My overall goal is to create MySQL users (despite `root`) automatically after the deployment in Kubernetes.

I found the following resources:
[How to create mysql users and database during deployment of mysql in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946194/how-to-create-mysql-users-and-database-during-deployment-of-mysql-in-kubernetes)
[Add another user to MySQL in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373869/add-another-user-to-mysql-in-kubernetes)

People suggested that `.sql` scripts can be mounted to `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` with a ConfigMap to create these users. In order to do that, I have to put the password of these users in this script in plain text. This is a potential security issue. Thus, I want to store MySQL usernames and passwords as Kubernetes Secrets.

This is my ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-config
  labels:
    app: mysql-image-db
data:
  initdb.sql: |-
    CREATE USER <user>@'%' IDENTIFIED BY <password>;
```

How can I access the associated Kubernetes secrets within this ConfigMap?

Comment: [Kubernetes Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) is similar to `ConfigMap` but different kubernetes object. In [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-cases) you can find use case. In Deployment you can refer to  `ConfigMap` and to `Secret`.  Also in [this guide](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/introduction-kubernetes-secrets-and-configmaps) you can find example with `Secret`, `ConfigMap` and `MySQL`. Please elaborate your final question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already know what Kubernetes Secrets and ConfigMaps are. I use a Secret to set the MySQL root password through an environment variable. However, there are no MySQL environment variables to set credentials for additional users. This is why I try to retrieve a Secret within a ConfigMap.

Comment: Im bit confused. In [How to create mysql users and database during deployment of mysql in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946194/how-to-create-mysql-users-and-database-during-deployment-of-mysql-in-kubernetes) you have example to use script. In [Add another user to MySQL in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373869/add-another-user-to-mysql-in-kubernetes) you have example to create configmap and than use in pod. Why associate ConfigMap with Secret when you can just use secret?

Comment: In Kubernetes docs you have example to use `Secret` as [Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) or [Environment Variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data) In this docs you also have 2 different methods. Do you need some specific scenario that you need to use Secret via ConfigMap?

Comment: I actually did't know, that you can mount the `Secret` as a Volume in a Pod and access it there. This could actually be a solution to my use case. I'll try it out if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am finally able to provide a solution to my own question. Since PjoterS made me aware that you can mount Secrets into a Pod as a volume, I came up with following solution.

This is the ConfigMap for the user creation scipt:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-init-script
  labels:
    app: mysql-image-db
data:
  init-user.sh: |-
    #!/bin/bash
    sleep 30s

    mysql -u root -p"$(cat /etc/mysql/credentials/root_password)" -e \
      "CREATE USER '$(cat /etc/mysql/credentials/user_1)'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$(cat /etc/mysql/credentials/password_1)';"
```

To made this work, I needed to mount the ConfigMap and the Secret as Volumes of my Deployment and added a `postStart` lifecycle hook to execute the user creation script.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-image-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-image-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-image-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:8.0
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: root_password
                  name: mysql-user-credentials
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            - name: mysql-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
            - name: mysql-init-script-volume
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/init
            - name: mysql-credentials-volume
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/credentials
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/etc/mysql/init/init-user.sh"]
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-volume-claim
        - name: mysql-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: mysql-config
        - name: mysql-init-script-volume
          configMap:
            name: mysql-init-script
            defaultMode: 0777
        - name: mysql-credentials-volume
          secret:
            secretName: mysql-user-credentials
```

Comment: Great. I'm glad you were able to solve it.